# What does the word "which" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

> "Association with real life events helps the author maintain the suspension of disbelief without **which**, a science fiction story becomes unrealistic."

I feel like "which" refers to "suspension of disbelief", but some people say it's "association with real-life events". Which interpretation is correct?

Comment: It's "suspension of disbelief".

Comment: Looks like the comma is misplaced as well. I'd move it to a position right after *disbelief*.

Comment: @Robusto i thought so too, but this is how it was written, and i tried to show you guys exactly what was there, in case it made a difference meaning-wise

Comment: Is this a transcription of someone speaking? I only ask because I can definitely hear someone saying that sentence and pausing on the *which*.

Comment: @Cantalouping i'm not sure whether it is, but it was a partof a  reading text in my english test.... For some reason though, the model answer is "association with real life events"...weird....

Comment: The original text has the comma after the word "disbelief", so it is actually a non-defining relative clause. See here [link](https://aedoglobal.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Reading-1.pdf)

Comment: @BillJ i guess you are right, i just copied it from the text i had in the test, sorry

Answer (score 1):

In your example

> Association with real life events helps the author maintain the suspension of disbelief without **which**, a science fiction story becomes unrealistic.

**which** refers to the

> suspension of disbelief

rephrased

> without **the suspension of disbelief**, a science fiction story becomes unrealistic.

Comment: I don't find the second sentence very helpful (because it reads so ungrammatically in itself); maybe there's some other way to show the relationships?

Comment: Sorry, i feel like the second sentence is incorrect too, as for the comma, it is in the wrong place

Comment: I've got to disagree on this one.  Association with real life events **helps** maintain the suspension of disbelief.  But it is the suspension of disbelief that is required to avoid the story becoming unrealistic.  "Without which" refers to the immediately preceding thing.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes, that is well explained